# left operand must be l-value

Tags: c, operand

could some one help. getting error with these 2 lines of code.  `num_red - count_red = red_pot;// all defined as 0`
and

```
while (count_red = 0 && count_yellow = 0 && count_green = 0 && count_brown = 0 && count_blue = 0 && count_pink = 0)
        {
            if (count_black = 0)
            {
                score = score + 7;
                printf("Score: %d\n", score);
                num_balls = num_balls - 1;
            }

        }
```

Comment: Almost everywhere you have `=`, you want `==`.

Comment: You cannot assign a value to the expression `num_red - count_red`. The expression's value is dictated by arithmetic rules, not your code.

Comment: Anthony- that was a silly mistake on my part. thank you,

Comment: Matt- any ideas on how i could work around num_red - count_red = red_pot

Comment: @user, how about write in plain language what you want that expression to be. Then we might be able to tell you how to write it.

Comment: im detecting snooker balls. when im detecting the colors i have num_red incrementing by 1 in a loop every time a red in detected. when a ball is potted, programme counts the reds.the reds that were on the table(red_num) - the reds on the table now(count) = the number of red balls potted if any(red_pot)

Comment: @user170705: I've added to my answer with the way to do this setting. You basically just have to set the unknown value based on the two known ones.

Comment: So you are saying red balls potted equals all red balls minus the red balls now on the table? That is `red_balls_potted = all_red_balls - red_balls_on_table;` In code, it is not `1 + 1 = 2`, it is `2 = 1 + 1;`, or rather `z = x + y;`. The result from the right is assigned to the variable on the left.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If that's a C-like language, you need to use `==` for equality checks, not `=`. The single `=` is for *assignment* so that:

```
int seven = 7;
int five = 5;
if (seven - five == 2) ...
```

is okay, but:

```
int seven = 7;
int five = 5;
if (seven - five = 2) ...
```

will, even if it compiles, not do what you expect.

You have a classic example in your code. The segment:

```
if (count_black = 0) blah;
```

will *not* execute `blah` when `count_black` is zero. It will *set* `count_black` to zero and steadfastly refuse to ever execute `blah`, since the result of `count_blah = 0` is 0 (false).

---

If you want the equality:

```
num_red - count_red == red_pot
```

to be true, you need to assign one of those variables (the "unknown" one) based on the other two "known" ones. For example, if `num_red` and `count_red` are known, set `red_pot` with:

```
red_pot = num_red - count_red;
```

Alternatively, if `red_pot` and `count_red` are known, set `num_red` with:

```
num_red = count_red + red_pot;
```

Comment: thank you all very much. the errors are now gone. much appreciated. cheers guys